# paypal sandbox unable to process request

Tags: paypal, sandbox, payment, paypal-sandbox

I've been working and testing the sandbox system paypal uses.

It have been confusing, I've created some testing accounts. At the moment I've created a form from my site. A "Buy now" button.

It's works as it should:

```
<form id="checkout" target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"  method="post">

    <input type="hidden" value="myemail@myaddres.com" name="business">
    <input type="hidden" value="Order" name="item_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="1000" name="amount">
    <input type="hidden" value="50" name="tax">
    <input type="hidden" value="SEK" name="currency_code">


    <input type="hidden" value="namehere" name="first_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="lastnamehere" name="last_name">
    <input type="hidden" value="emailaddressaere" name="email">

    <input type="hidden" value="addresshere" name="address1">
    <input type="hidden" value="cityhere" name="city">
    <input type="hidden" value="SE" name="country">

    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="address_override">


    <input type="hidden" value="http://www.mydomain.com/thanks" name="return">
    <input type="hidden" value="http://www.mydomain.com/checkout" name="cancel_return">

    <input type="hidden" value="uniqueid" name="invoice">
    <input type="hidden" value="sale" name="paymentaction">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">

    <input type="submit" value="Buy" />
</form>
```

I'm sure (I think I'm) that the HTML is right (just that the inputs should end with /> )

Well, at paypal, I login and confirm the payment. Everything works great until I confirm it then **the weird stuffs keep happening every time.** So when I confirm the payment this is what happends:

> Your account information has changed. Either you clicked "Pay" more
>   than once but the original transfer was already made, or you just
>   received money. To check, please view your account History and make
>   sure you want to perform this transaction.

AND:

> At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to
>   facilitator account's Test Store and try another option.

Now after all this, it seems that the no payment was made, but the case is that a payment has been sent to the "business email". I just login with it, but there I have to confirm the payment.

Why is this happening? Why isn't it being confirmed?

I just started with paypal today. I've been fighting with it the whole day long (+night) Now I just had to ask.

Comment: I am getting same problem just now, have you got any solution ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error as well

Comment: Have you tried to clear your cookies from the browser. I tried with a fresh browser and it worked

Comment: you are absolutely right, i tried with chrome and it worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Have you tried to clear your cookies from the browser. I tried with a
>   fresh browser and it work

As @chell said. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, it works in other browser OR after clearing browser cookies/cache. Thanks.

Comment: I selectively killed all cookies with names containing the word "paypal", and now everything is working normally! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**The Below Solution worked for me.**

**The situation was:**
I was not able to pay using Credit Card which was by default attach to Sandbox  account

**Solution:**
I created a new Credit Card using ***'Credit Card Generator'*** option in Paypal Developer Account and used this new Credit Card credentials at the time of payment

*Reference Link:* https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sandbox-Environment/Sorry-your-bank-wasn-t-able-to-verify-your-X-at-this-time-Please/m-p/2189760/highlight/true#M6370

Answer (score -1):

I've got it..
Clearing cookies won't solve your problem...

Solution: (worked for me)

1. Created the business account setting country as "India".
2. Created the buyer account setting country as "United States".

And tried Sandbox payment, it worked!     :D(feeling happy)

Comment: I am uncertain how this answers the original question.  The OP did not appear to be dealing with an international purchase situation.