# At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to Test Store and try another option

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to create a billing agreement in my sandbox environment but got this cryptic error:

> At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to [my] Test Store and try another option.

How would I debug this?

My code so far includes:

1. Create an API token
2. Creating a billing plan
3. Activate the billing plan
4. Create the billing agreement

Everything works until step 4.

I'm using the code from the REST PHP SDK samples.

This problem was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775951/paypal-sandbox-unable-to-process-request) by clearing the cache. I've tried that as well as another newly installed browser, but the problem remains.

Tips?

**Edit**: Billing agreements are enabled in the app as stated [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/300). It might be specific to Germany, as I am in Germany too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately it is specific to Germany:

"Recurring payments cannot be created for buyers in Germany or China. In this case, you can use reference transactions as an alternate solution."

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/#limitations

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

1. Login to PayPal. https://www.paypal.com/signin
2. Go to the Sandbox Test Accounts
   https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts
3. Create a new
   personal sandbox test account (email address, password, country,
   verified, etc). If you see no create button, then you will have to
   clone one by clicking on the icon at the right the table row. Just
   make sure you are cloning one of type PERSONAL.
4. Clear the PayPal cookies using your browser settings. (This will log you out of PayPal)
5. Now, you can run your script and when you are redirected to PayPal for
   payment approval you will have to type the credentials of the newly
   created personal test account.

In short, what I suggest you do is creating a new personal sandbox test account and clearing your browser cookies.

Good luck