# Paypal : We are not able to process payment using PayPal account at this time. Please return to the merchant

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to accept Paypal payments and i used Express Checkout C# SDK.

But when i'm trying to do a payment, i'm getting a paypal page with this message

"**We are not able to process payment using PayPal account at this time. Please return to the merchant" and a button to return to merchant site (cancel url**)".

Automatically created accounts (country FR) are not working so i tried to create US accounts not working too. All my accounts are verified.

I tried also to clean my browser cookies [(see this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775951/paypal-sandbox-unable-to-process-request)

Does anyone have a guess ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem. What I noticed is that if the buyer test account only has a credit card as funding option, then I get the error as soon as I login with the test account. If, on the other hand, the test account also has a Banking Account funding option, then the login succeeds, but I can only choose the Banking Account option and not the credit card to complete the payment.

If in your case you don't need to test the credit card option, **perhaps this could be a solution**.

Also, on the official PayPal documentation I read that, in order to accept credit cards, you need to upgrade the business account to a Pro account:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_about-accounts/

I tried that, but it did not help in my case

Comment: @alvinmeimoun I contacted now the paypal support, as the issue persists. I will report back as soon as I get an aswer

Comment: @alvinmeimoun The PayPal support helped tracking down the issue. The cause was the purchase amount that was too high (> 1000 EUR). According to the PayPal support, this can trigger errors like the one you reported in certain circumstances (e.g. buyer's account not fully verified).

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is add `"allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"`

```
  "transactions": [
      {
        "amount": {
          "total": data.grandTotal,
          "currency": "AUD",
          "details": {
            "subtotal": (data.subTotal - totalDiscount).toFixed(2),
            "shipping": data.shipping,
            "handling_fee": data.handling,
            "insurance": data.insurance
          }
        },
        "description": "My orders",
        "payment_options": {
          "allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"
        },
```